# JFileChooser change text from menu buttons

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, uimanager

I want to change the "List" button text under the "View Menu" menu, but i can't find the way to do it. Here is a picture of the file chooser window.

[JFileChooser dialog window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlueq.png)

I tried these, but didn't work:

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonText", "Test1");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonName", "Test2");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listButtonText", "Test3");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewButtonAccessibleName", "Test4");
chooser.updateUI();
```

Has anyone encoutered this? Also, if possible i would like to change right click menu texts as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the values that must be changed:

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewActionLabelText", "mytext");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.listViewActionLabelText", "myothertext");
```

[image: preview]

You can see the installed values in `sun.swing.FilePane` class in `installDefaults` method:

```
protected void installDefaults() {
    Locale l = getFileChooser().getLocale();

    listViewBorder = UIManager.getBorder("FileChooser.listViewBorder");
    listViewBackground = UIManager.getColor("FileChooser.listViewBackground");
    listViewWindowsStyle = UIManager.getBoolean("FileChooser.listViewWindowsStyle");
    readOnly = UIManager.getBoolean("FileChooser.readOnly");

    // TODO: On windows, get the following localized strings from the OS

    viewMenuLabelText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.viewMenuLabelText", l);
    refreshActionLabelText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.refreshActionLabelText", l);
    newFolderActionLabelText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.newFolderActionLabelText", l);

    viewTypeActionNames = new String[VIEWTYPE_COUNT];
    viewTypeActionNames[VIEWTYPE_LIST] = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.listViewActionLabelText", l);
    viewTypeActionNames[VIEWTYPE_DETAILS] = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.detailsViewActionLabelText", l);

    kiloByteString = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.fileSizeKiloBytes", l);
    megaByteString = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.fileSizeMegaBytes", l);
    gigaByteString = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.fileSizeGigaBytes", l);
    fullRowSelection = UIManager.getBoolean("FileView.fullRowSelection");

    renameErrorTitleText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.renameErrorTitleText", l);
    renameErrorText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.renameErrorText", l);
    renameErrorFileExistsText = UIManager.getString("FileChooser.renameErrorFileExistsText", l);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the right way! Do you also know how i can change the menu labels when the mouse (right click) is used?

Comment: Although i needed only 3 lines, you gave the code to make it automatically depending on the local language. Thank you though, because it was what i asked!